# Using the Python GData API, cannot get editable video entry

Tags: python, django, youtube, gdata, gdata-api

I am having trouble getting a video entry which includes a link rel="edit". I need such an entry in order to be able to call `DeleteVideoEntry(...)` on it.

I am retrieving the video using `GetYouTubeVideoEntry(youtube_id=XXXXXXX)`. My yt_service is initialized with a username, password, and a developer key. I use ProgrammaticLogin. This part seems to work fine. I use the same yt_service to upload said video earlier. Also, if I change the developer key to something bogus (during debugging) and try to authenticate, I get a 403 error. This leads me to believe that authentication works OK.

Needsless to say, the video entry retrieved with `GetYouTubeVideoEntry(youtube_id=XXXXXXX)` does not contain the edit link and I cannot use the entry in a `DeleteVideoEntry(...)` call.

Is there some special way to get a video entry which will contain a link element with a  rel="edit"? Can anyone suggest some way to resolve my issue? Could this possibly be a bug?

**Update:**

For the records, when I tried getting the feed of all my uploads, and then looping through the video entries, the video entries do have an edit link. So using this works:

```
uri = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/%s/uploads' % username
feed = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoFeed(uri)
for entry in feed.entry:
   yt_service.DeleteVideoEntry(entry)
```

But this does not:

```
entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id = video.youtube_id)
yt_service.DeleteVideoEntry(entry)
```

Using the same yt_service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just deleted youtube video using gdata and ProgrammaticLogin()

Here is some steps to reproduce:

```
import gdata.youtube.service
yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()

yt_service.developer_key = 'developer_key'
yt_service.email = 'email'
yt_service.password = 'password'
yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin()


# video_id should looks like 'iu6Gq-tUsTc'
uri = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/%s/uploads/%s' % (username, video_id)  
entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeUserEntry(uri=uri)
response = yt_service.DeleteVideoEntry(entry)
print response  # True
```

`yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoFeed(uri)` works because `GetYouTubeVideoFeed` doesn't check uri and just calls `self.Get(uri, ...)` but originaly, I think, it expected `'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos'` uri.

vice versa `yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry()` use `YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URI = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos'` but this entry doesn't contains `rel="edit"`

Hope that helps you out

Answer (score 1):

You can view the HTTP headers of the generated requests by setting the debug flag to true.  This is as simple as:

```
 yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
 yt_service.debug = True
```

[You can read about this in the documentation here.](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/debugging_client_libs.html#python)